# Convert SQL Query into Django ORM Query

Tags: sql, django

I have this sql query, I need to use Django ORM format

```sql
delete from foodies_orderstall as os
where os.order = <order-id> and
not exists (
  select *
  from foodies_ordermenu as om
  where om.order_stall = os.id
);
```

[image: django models]

Comment: Share models in question

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be like this:

```
OrderStall.objects.filter(order_id=order_id, ordermenu__isnull=True).delete()
```

This works because of [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) between OrderMenu and OrderStall. Also, I am checking if there is any `ordermenu` by [`__isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#std-fieldlookup-isnull).

Comment: i got this error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'ordermenu' into field. Choices are: id, menus, order, order_id, stall, stall_id`

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding related_name to the relationship. Thank u so much @ruddra

Comment: Great! @DanielChristianMandolang please consider accepting this answer. Thanks